# CakePHP error for the connexion with ACL

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to understand how Cakephp works.  I built a connection system with a simple form (username and password). When I click on the submit button (with the correct username and password), I always receive the same flash message, "Your username or password was incorrect". I tried many things, but I don't know how to fix it . 
If I'm logged, I want to be redirect on Google (it's the test i try) .

Look at my code :

login.ctp (View)

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action'=>'login'));
echo $this->Form->inputs(array('legend'=>'Se connecter','username','password'));
echo $this->Form->end('Se connecter'); 
?>
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow();
    }
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user("id");
                $this->redirect('http://www.google.fr');
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

User (Model)

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model', 'AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class User extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    public function parentNode() {
        if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
            $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
        } else {
            $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
        }
        if (!$groupId) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
        }
    }

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        return true;
    }

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
?>
```

The password in my table user (sql) :

```
 password   char(40)    latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: is your password hashed in the database? If yes, you should be careful with the (40).

Comment: yes it is . Thanks for the advice and what about my problem for the connexion ?